# how to continue with uploading a csv file to postgres using flask+panda

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, flask

i am new to python and postgres and am trying to build a simple flask web app.
a user can choose a csv file, press upload, and it will create a table in postgres on my server with the table in the csv.
a simple copy paste.

**my html code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>upload</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="POST" enctype=multipart/form-data action ="\upload">
      <input type="file" name="user_file">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**my python module:**

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template, send_file, request
    import pandas as pd
    import csv
    import sqlalchemy as sa
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route("/upload", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
    def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'user_file' in request.files:
       csvfile = request.files['user_file']
       con=sa.create_engine('postgresql://user:password@localhost/dbname')
       chunks = pd.read_csv(csvfile, chunksize=100000)
       for chunk in chunks:
          chunk.to_sql(name='table', if_exist='append', con=con)

    return render_template('new.html')


    if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

when i try to create a connection string to the postgres server, create a table, and copy the csv to it, i get a web page with this:
**sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError
OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "__localhost_" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
 (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)**

tried finding the answer online with no luck.
Your help will be very appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I don't see a user, password in your connection string, "dialect+driver://username:password@host:port/database"

Comment: ive edited my question to reflect what exactly isnt working.
can you pls specify how can i correct my conn string?
i suspected that it was the problem (one of them)

Comment: it doesn't appear postgresql is running on port 5432 on localhost, so check that...

Comment: as i understand, that's the default port postgres is listening on